Annotations not working as intended in Kotlin
I have a question regarding how annotations in Kotlin are supposed to work.
First, I created an annotation class called AltArg:
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class AltArg(val name : String)

Then, I annotated some properties of a class I created called Student:
class Student @JvmOverloads constructor (
    val name: String,
    @AltArg("id") val nr: Int,
    @AltArg("birthplace") val from: String,
    @AltArg("evaluation") val grades: List<Grade> = emptyList()
)

After, I created a test to check if the annotations were being recognized, but this test always fails. The call Student::class.annotations doesn’t return any of the annotations in it, so its size is always zero.
@Test fun checkAltArgAnnotationsInStudent() {
    val annotations = Student::class.annotations
    assertEquals(3, annotations.size)
}

This is the first time I’m using annotations and I don’t really understand why this isn’t working. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for the help!

Doesn't that return the annotations on the class itself, not its members? In other words, isn't annotations.size == 1?

Even if that was the case, I don't really know, it should still be 1 and not 0 as it stands now.

Yes, sorry, 0. That's still correct as the annotation is on the constructor, not the class.

Student::class.annotations only gives you the annotations that are present on the Student class itself, and you have none here.
You have one annotation on the constructor of the Student class (@JvmOverloads), and one annotation on some properties (@AltArg).
To access annotations on properties, you first need to get the properties of the class. Since properties are members of the class (like methods), you can access them via Student::class.members. Here is a sample that shows how to access their annotations:
Student::class.members.forEach { m ->
    println("Annotations of member '${m.name}': ${m.annotations}")
}

prints:
Annotations of member 'from': [@AltArg(name="birthplace")]
Annotations of member 'grades': [@AltArg(name="evaluation")]
Annotations of member 'name': []
Annotations of member 'nr': [@AltArg(name="id")]
Annotations of member 'equals': []
Annotations of member 'hashCode': []
Annotations of member 'toString': []

Note about annotation retention
Note that @JvmOverloads has BINARY retention, which means it's present in the compiled classes but it's invisible for reflection (reflection is the process of introspecting the code like we're doing here). So, even if you tried to go through the constructors of the class and look for their annotations, you would not see it.
On the other hand, @AltArg has the default retention (RUNTIME). That's why the code above works and you can see the annotations at runtime via reflection.

Ok, I think I get it now. I thought I was checking the annotations of the properties of the class, but what I was actually doing was checking the annotations of the class itself, is that it?
